# How to store multiple dataclass values and find new url

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have created a small script that scraped a webpage that scrapes all items name, link, image and price from a product table.

I am currently facing problem where I am not able to store multiple dataclasses where I want to first of all see if there is a new URL found in the webpage and if there is a new change, I want to print out the name, image and price of the new url that has been found.

```
import time
from typing import Optional

import attr
import requests
from selectolax.parser import HTMLParser


@attr.dataclass
class Info:
    store: str = attr.ib(factory=str)
    link: str = attr.ib(factory=str)
    name: Optional[str] = attr.ib(factory=str)
    price: Optional[str] = attr.ib(factory=str)
    image: Optional[str] = attr.ib(factory=str)


# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Get all latest products found in the webpage
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
def from_page():
    with requests.get("https://www.footish.se/sneakers", timeout=5) as rep:
        if rep.status_code in (200, 404):
            doc = HTMLParser(rep.text)
            for product in doc.css('article.product-wrapper'):
                name = product.css_first('div.product-image > a').attributes.get('title')
                link = product.css_first('div.product-image > a').attributes.get('href')
                image = product.css_first('div.product-image > a > img').attributes.get('data-original')
                price = product.css_first('span.price-amount')

            return Info(
                store="Footish",
                link=link,
                name=name,
                image=image,
                price=price
            )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    all_found_products = set()

    while True:
        get_all_products: Info = from_page()

        diff = set(get_all_products.link) - all_found_products

        for new_urls in diff:
            print(f"Found new url! {new_urls}")
            print(f"Name: {get_all_products.name}")
            print(f"image: {get_all_products.image}")
            print(f"price: {get_all_products.price}")


        print("Sleeping 120 sec")
        time.sleep(120)
```

My problem is that I dont know how return dataclasses that is looped from a for loop `for product in doc.css('article.product-wrapper'):` as there is multiple products on the webpage and I want to store all found products and then compare to see if there is a new url found and if there is then I would like to print out the name, price and image of the new url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `list` to store multiple `Info` instances, then return them all

```
def from_page():
    with requests.get("https://www.footish.se/sneakers", timeout=5) as rep:
        if rep.status_code in (200, 404):
            doc = HTMLParser(rep.text)
            infos = []
            for product in doc.css('article.product-wrapper'):
                name = product.css_first('div.product-image > a').attributes.get('title')
                link = product.css_first('div.product-image > a').attributes.get('href')
                image = product.css_first('div.product-image > a > img').attributes.get('data-original')
                price = product.css_first('span.price-amount')

                infos.append(Info(store="Footish", link=link, name=name,
                                  image=image, price=price))

            return infos
```

And for the main, it would be more something like

```
all_found_urls = set()

while True:
    get_all_products = from_page()

    for info in get_all_products:
        if info.link not in all_found_urls:
            print(f"Found new url! {info.link}")
            print(f"Name: {info.name}")
            print(f"image: {info.image}")
            print(f"price: {info.price}")
            all_found_urls.add(info.link)

    print("Sleeping 120 sec")
    time.sleep(120)
```

Comment: Hi Azro! Thank you so much for the answer. I think the issue with using `get_all_products = from_page(); for info in get_all_products:` I will then lose the autocompletion with type hinting if I type e.g. info.link. Is there any way to not lose it?

Comment: @ProtractorNewbie I have no problem about that, you can be more precise with `get_all_products: List[Info] = from_page()` `from typing import List`